# Microsoft Edge Developer Tools window stays blank

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-edge, developer-tools

The dev tools window for Microsoft Edge currently looks like this on my system:

[image: Empty Microsoft Edge Developer Tools window]

This has worked before. I don't know why and when exactly this change happened.

I'm on Windows 10.0.14393 and Microsoft Edge 38.14393.0.0.

The dev tools for Internet Explorer 11.953.14393.0 are still functional.

Any ideas?

Comment: me too! used to work (i mean, it would crash pretty often, but hey, IE/Edge)

Comment: I was running into the same issue recently. I was able to open F12 from an InPrivate tab as a work around though.

Comment: I have the same problem, private mode does not work either. there are support tickets open at microsoft but not much activity

Comment: Had the same issue here. Three years old at this point and it appears Edge is still not Production Ready. Seems typical for MS as of late.

Comment: Anyone know if this is a Group Policy thing? This only seemed to happen after changing to a different company domain on my computer.

Comment: Having this same problem, it has to be the Group Policy

Answer (score 0):

I opened the devtools in InPrivate-Mode, unfortunately they were empty there too. But after about 5 min they appeared all by themselves :D And now the devtools are working in the normal Tabs also. Magic.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Solved by going to https://www.microsoft.com/edge . Downloaded edge setup and reinstalled it. Then the DevTools started to work again

Answer (score 0):

From the left sidebar, select the Apps & Features option. Select Advanced options for the Microsoft Edge browser application from the list. Click the button labeled "Repair" at the bottom. You can also try resetting the browser by clicking the Reset button if the problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

f the Microsoft Edge Engineer Devices window stays clear or shows no happy, there could be a few purposes behind this issue. You can try the following troubleshooting steps to fix the issue:

Update Microsoft Edge: Ensure you are utilizing the most recent rendition of Microsoft Edge. Refreshes frequently incorporate bug fixes and enhancements that can determine similarity issues with the Designer Instruments.

Start up Microsoft Edge again: Restart Microsoft Edge after closing all instances. In some cases, a basic restart can determine impermanent errors.

Clear Program Store: Any corrupted or out-of-date data that might be causing the problem can be eliminated by clearing the browser's cache. To clear the cache, navigate to the browser's settings and select either the "Clear browsing data" or "Clear cache" option.

Turn off Extensions: Developer Tools functionality may be compromised by some browser add-ons or extensions. Disable any extensions you have installed for a short time, then check to see if the Developer Tools window starts showing content.

Check the settings of Developer Tools: To access the settings, open the Developer Tools and select the gear icon or menu with three dots. Check to see that "Enable CSS" and "Enable JavaScript" are both turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Apps & Features option from the left sidebar. Find the Microsoft Edge browser application from the list and click on Advanced options. Scroll down and click on the Repair button. If the issue persists then you can also try to click the Reset button to reset the browser.

Comment: Why did you copy a [previous answer](https://superuser.com/a/1786656/763386)?

Comment: @Toto It seems to be plagiarizing [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60733077/1178016) verbatim, while the one you linked seems to have rephrased the same answer. Weird.

Comment: those are AI-generated spam

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was some (still unknown to me) user setting that was causing this issue.  Deleting the user preferences directory (which can be found by navigating to `edge://versoin` and searching for the preferences path) worked for me.

Comment: `edge://versoin` does not seem correct.  Do you by chance mean `edge://version`?